# How do I measure intensity of sound in real time?

Tags: matlab, audio, psychtoolbox

I need to program a function that records an audio response, but when the voice of the person speaking reaches a certain intensity I need to know it on-line. Currently I am using this for recording:

```
PsychPortAudio('GetAudioData')
```

I can't analyze the intensity of the voice (using norm for example) on-line.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the analoginput command.

```
AI = analoginput('winsound');
addchannel(AI,1);
```

Then use:

```
x = getdata(AI, t);
```

To collect it.  You'll need to set up some buffer length (say 1 second) and get the data, then perform whatever amplitude analysis you want.